# Simulate categorical variable with known values for each level

Tags: simulate

I would like to simulate a categorical variable with n = 5 levels for a panel dataset. I will be associating the variable with a continuous outcome in the context of a linear mixed effects model (nlme package). If I know the coefficients for each level relative to the reference level, how would I simulate this variable and add it to the continuous outcome y?

e.g. 
Level 1 - Reference

Level 2 - 0.75 (When Categorical variable = Level 2, the coefficient is 0.75)

Level 3 - 0.19 (When Categorical variable = Level 2, the coefficient is 0.19)

Level 4 - 0.59 (When Categorical variable = Level 2, the coefficient is 0.59)

Level 5 - 0.89 (When Categorical variable = Level 2, the coefficient is 0.89)

y <- Beta0 + Beta1Intervention + Beta2Categoricalvariable + Beta3Categoricalvariable + Beta4Categorical + Beta5Categorical + random_effectcluster + random_effectindividual

The idea here would be that the coefficient/value of the categorical variable would be defined a priori (as above) for each individual in the dataset. I hope this makes sense.

I tried doing the following:

```
y <- defDataAdd(varname = "Y", formula = "17.87 + 5.0*Ijt + timecoeff1*I(period == 1) + timecoeff2*I(period == 2) + timecoeff3*I(period == 3) + timecoeff4*I(period == 4) + timecoeff5*I(period == 5) + u_3 + u_2 + error", dist = "normal")
```

But...R gives me the following error message....

**Error: Variable(s) referenced not previously defined: timecoeff1, timecoeff2, timecoeff3, timecoeff4, timecoeff5**

If instead, I replace the timecoeff* with an actual integer, it works fine....

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I tried doing the following:

y <- defDataAdd(varname = "Y", formula = "17.87 + 5.0*Ijt + timecoeff1*I(period == 1) + timecoeff2*I(period == 2) + timecoeff3*I(period == 3) + timecoeff4*I(period == 4) + timecoeff5*I(period == 5) + u_3 + u_2 + error", dist = "normal")


But...R gives me the following error message....

Error: Variable(s) referenced not previously defined: timecoeff1, timecoeff2, timecoeff3, timecoeff4, timecoeff5

If instead, I replace the timecoeff* with an actual integer, it works fine....

Does anyone know why?